# How to check the checkbox CellTemplate based on the Datagrid Row Selection?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

clicking anywhere on the dataGrid row, the checkbox need to be checked & corresponding checkbox trigger action  should perform.
    Sample code Skeleton.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <CheckBox>
                      //Checked/unchecked Interaction.Triggers>
                 </CheckBox>
             </DataTemplate>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i;i<=dataGridView1.Rows.Count;i++)
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell CbxCell = row.Cells[i] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
if (CbxCell!=null && !DBNull.Value.Equals(CbxCell.Value) && (bool)CbxCell.Value == true)
{
    // Logic You Want to implement
}
}
```

Comment: I want to handled in XAML if not possible then ViewModel. But in my datagrid i don't have DataGridViewCheckBoxCell instead it is datatemplate with checkbox control.